# Get single glyph metrics (.net)

Tags: .net, fonts, glyph, fontmetrics

How can I get full information about single glyph from choosen font (for example Arial -> symbol "A")

This picture describe what variables I need to find:

[image: Glyph metrics]

Answer (score 3):

You can start with the FontFamily class.

and this CP article http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ExtendedGraphicsII.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I don't think FontFamily will give any information about a particular glyph, but the DirectWrite interface might work: (I haven't used it yet)

- [Glyphs and Glyph Runs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd941785%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [IDWriteFontFace::GetGlyphIndices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370998%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [IDWriteFontFace::GetDesignGlyphMetrics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370986%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes, with IDWriteFontFace::GetGlyphIndices GetMetrics, GetGlyphMetrics, and IDWriteFontFace1::GetCaretMetrics, using the DWRITE_FONT_METRICS::ascent/descent/xHeight/capHeight, DWRITE_GLYPH_METRICS::width, DWRITE_CARET_METRICS::slopeRise/slopeRun.